# Why there is 'the' before 'abode'?

Tags: articles

> An abbey near an abattoir is the abode of the monks.

I have checked it via QuillBot that had marked 'an' as a mistake.

Comment: "An abode" suggests one of many. Do the monks have several places where they live?

Comment: "The abode of" someone is "the place where they live" - similarly, "the home of".

Comment: It would be 'an' (indefinite article) abode of the monks if the monks have more than one abode (or home) and this is one of them, and it would be 'the' (definite article) abode of the monks if it is the only abode of the monks.

Comment: Countable, common nouns usually have an article. There are countless questions about this matter on the site, have a search and you'll find the answer.

Comment: People with a Cyrillic background often seem to have trouble with articles.

Comment: The address is about one abode.

Comment: @Peter, I wanted to express that many abbeys exist over the world, but the abbey is one of them where these monks are living, and they are living only at it.

Comment: And the abode is the first occurrence of the abode in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the monks had multiple different abodes, then "an abode" would be correct. However, it seems likely that the monks have only one abode, since they are assigned to a single abbey. So, in context, "the abode" is correct.